# Difference between variable and string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between `variable` and `string` in `c#`

Why the `c#` is supporting only this

```
var data = GetData("");
```

Why not this?

```
string data = GetData("");
```

Or it will support both? Which one is better to use ? How it is implemented?

```
  private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: var is only a shortcurt it's not a type, if `GetData()` returns string, then `var = string` in **this case**

Comment: What's `GetData` in this case? Without knowing what it's declared to return, we can't answer the question.

Comment: If you're basically asking "what does `var` do?" then you should read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: your getdata() return datatable,

Comment: so if it returns `datatable` is it fair enough to use `var`

Answer (score 4):

The type of var is not specified in code rather *compiler* infers it from the `code`. GetData probably does not return a `string`.

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you
>   had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.
>   The following two declarations of i are functionally equivalent, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

**Edit** based on updated OP

You **can not assign DataTable to string** they are two different types. You can use `DataTable` instead of var if you want to specify the *type* yourself and you do not want to the compiler to determine it for you using `var`.

```
string data = GetData("");
```

Answer (score 0):

if `GetData` method return type is `string` below will work

```
string data = GetData("");
```

but return type of `GetData` method is `DataTable` , you can change the code as

```
DataTable data = GetData("");
```

Or use `var` and compiler will determines the type for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Var` is an implicit type.
 It aliases any type in the C# programming language.
 The aliased type is determined by the C# compiler, where as string is string variable type

Answer (score 0):

`var` is not a data type. Declaring something as `var` is synonymous to saying "Compiler, I want you to figure out what type this variable should be by looking at the object I assign to it". Assume you had this:

```
var myString = "This is a string!";
```

The C# compiler looks ahead to see that you are assigning a string to `myString` and it knows that `myString` is going to be a `string` type. As far as the compiler is concerned, it is exactly the same as:

```
string myString = "This is a string!";
```

As far as what you should use, its entirely your preference and choosing one over the other will not impact your code at all. Personally, I use `var` because I feel its redundant to declare an object's type twice, like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

Instead I prefer:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
```

Again, its entirely up to you and your personal coding style. Hope this clears up your questions!